# min3d Invalid float: ""

Tags: android, 3d, min3d

I want to load a car model with min3d but I am getting this error:

```
05-16 15:21:43.132    5677-5690/com.example.OBD2TestApp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 249
Process: com.example.OBD2TestApp, PID: 5677
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""
        at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
        at java.lang.StringToReal.parseFloat(StringToReal.java:289)
        at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:300)
        at min3d.parser.ObjParser.readMaterialLib(ObjParser.java:196)
        at min3d.parser.ObjParser.parse(ObjParser.java:107)
        at com.example.OBD2TestApp.Test3D.initScene(Test3D.java:52)
        at min3d.core.Scene.init(Scene.java:254)
        at min3d.core.Renderer.onSurfaceCreated(Renderer.java:75)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1501)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

Comment: Can you post some code? It will help figure out the issue.

Comment: I think the problem is that the obj file is to big and the library cannot load the object. When i use another, smaller obj file it works fine.